# Wrong user registration date in wordpress

Tags: user-registration, date

I have this funny problem and I'm not able to locate where it happens.
The problem is when a user registers on my site his/her registration date is wrong (not just wrong but total rubbish, even if I add them manually from the admin panel).
I tried deactivating every plugin and theme installed on wordpress to no avail.
The problem persists no matter what. Here is a screen shot from phpmyadmin.
[image]
Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that the database was somehow malfunctioning. I tried repairing the table and it seems to have worked for now. Though I had to reset all the dates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like a SQL injection attack.

The `'/0--+-(( +):(*:*-` part that is...

Comment: It can't be. It happens when a new user registers. I mentioned it happens even from the admin panel.

Comment: Do you have any plugins that could mess with the userinfo?

Comment: `I tried deactivating every plugin and theme installed on wordpress to no avail.`